# Elegant way to deserialise EnumSet from String

Tags: java, enums, enumset

I'd like to serialise some `EnumSet<FooType>` to `String` using its `toString()` method.

E.g.: `EnumSet.of(FooType.COMMON, FooType.MEDIUM).toString()` will give `[COMMON, MEDIUM]`.

The question is about an elegant way to deserialise such a string back to the `EnumSet<FooSet>`. I'm looking for some commonly known library (may be like `apache-commons`) or a standard Util-class for such things.

Something like: `EnumSetUtil.valueOf(FooType.class, "[COMMON, MEDIUM]")`

I've implemented this thing in such way:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> valueOf(Class<E> eClass, String str) {
    String[] arr = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).split(",");
    EnumSet<E> set = EnumSet.noneOf(eClass);
    for (String e : arr) set.add(E.valueOf(eClass, e.trim()));
    return set;
}
```

But, may be there is a ready solution, or a dramatically easy way for doing this.

Comment: I know of no such library, and your method looks pretty good.  I would probably use a regex (_personal preference_) instead, and call the method `fromString` to imply its inverse relationship to `toString` (though the java convention would likely be something like `parseEnumSet`), but I don't find any flaw in what you are doing.

Comment: Serializing and deserializing "by hand" is often faster and easier to debug for simple structures but you usually hit pretty fast the corner cases: for example what happens if one your enums contains a comma `,` ? Then you will need to start escaping commas and complicate your regex, etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Java 8 you can do something like this with [Lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) and streams:

```
EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.asList(str.split(","))
.stream().map(FooType::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

Answer (score 0):

With guava 19.0:

```
    Iterable<String> i = Splitter.on(",")
        .trimResults(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE.or(CharMatcher.anyOf("[]")))
        .split(str);
    Set<YourEnum> result = FluentIterable.from(i)
        .transform(Enums.stringConverter(YourEnum.class)).toSet();
```

OR another way with JSON library if you can accept String format like this `['COMMON', 'MEDIUM']`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gson ('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1') library you can do:

```
public static EnumSet getEnumObject(Type type, String jsonStrToDeserialize) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return jsonStrToDeserialize == null ? null : (EnumSet) gson.fromJson(jsonStrToDeserialize, type);
}
```